# Calculating monthly sales based on a quarter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to calculate the monthly sales for a given quarter.

Here is my code to calculate the previous quarter.

```
set @quarter = datepart(QQ, getdate()) - 1

if @quarter = 0 
    begin
    set @quarter = 4
    set @year = datepart(year, getdate()) -1
    end
else set @year = datepart(year, getdate())
```

Here is my code to calculate the average monthly sales for the entire quarter.

```
SELECT TOP 5 d.sdealer_name, COUNT(c.icontract_id) / 3 as 'AverageMonthlySales'
FROM dealers d 
INNER JOIN contracts c 
    ON c.sdealer_number = d.sdealer_number 
WHERE (d.sdealer_number NOT LIKE '%demo%' 
  AND d.sdealer_status in ('A', 'R') 
  AND c.sagent_number = @sagent_number
  AND c.sstatus in ('P', 'A', 'C', 'E') 
  AND c.iproduct_type_id in (4)
  AND DATEPART(QQ, c.dtcontract_sale_date) = @quarter 
  AND DATEPART(year, c.dtcontract_sale_date) = @year)
GROUP BY  d.sdealer_name
ORDER BY COUNT(distinct c.icontract_id) desc
```

How would I calculate the total sales for each month dynamically for the given quarter?

Answer (score 0):

ctrl+h ... just replace quarter datepart with month. is there some reason you haven't tried that?

```
set @month = datepart(month, getdate()) - 1

if @month = 0 
    begin
    set @month = 12
    set @year = datepart(year, getdate()) -1
    end
else set @year = datepart(year, getdate())

SELECT TOP 5 d.sdealer_name, COUNT(c.icontract_id) as 'AverageMonthlySales'
FROM dealers d 
INNER JOIN contracts c 
    ON c.sdealer_number = d.sdealer_number 
WHERE (d.sdealer_number NOT LIKE '%demo%' 
  AND d.sdealer_status in ('A', 'R') 
  AND c.sagent_number = @sagent_number
  AND c.sstatus in ('P', 'A', 'C', 'E') 
  AND c.iproduct_type_id in (4)
  AND DATEPART(month, c.dtcontract_sale_date) = @month 
  AND DATEPART(year, c.dtcontract_sale_date) = @year)
GROUP BY  d.sdealer_name
ORDER BY COUNT(distinct c.icontract_id) desc
```

Comment: For "given quarter", you may still need add the quarter criteria.

Comment: Nope. Datepart( month, n ) = {1,2,3} == datepart( qq, n ) = 1 and so forth for q's 2, 3, and 4. Try it out with your dataset

Comment: I'm not sure how this is supposed to duplicate what was needed without adding a lot of code to check which quarter it is in (which SQL does automatically with QQ).

For example running your code @month is returning 5 when it should be returning (1/2/3).  As the previous quarter would be months (1/2/3).

I was trying to avoid adding several if statements (if @month = 1,2,3) @quarter = 1) etc..

There is a big difference between `datepart(qq, getdate()) - 1` and `datepart(month, getdate()) - 1`

I was hoping there was some sql magic built in to handle it, but it doesn't look that way so far.

Comment: The difference between `datepart( qq )` and `datepart( month )` is self-apparent: the number of periods for either quarter or date since the beginning of the given year. `datepart( month, '2015-05-31' )` will always equal 5. Likewise, `datepart( qq, '2015-05-31' )` will always equal 2. If you want single-month grouping, you have it with the example I provided. You should note that using the OP code, you were returning a 1/3 average since the beginning of the current quarter ( 2015-04-01 ), not of the past 3 months.

Comment: I'm not sure why you removed the `DATEPART(qq)` since this is the information I need to keep track of.  I need to check the sale for the previous quarter which would be the `months (1,2,3)`.  Your query is returning the month of May which is outside my criteria.

The only way I can see making what I need work is with more IF statements.  If quarter = 1 then @month1 = jan @month2 = feb etc...  I would have to add many more if statements if I were to use `DATEPART(m)`.

I appreciate the time and answer however, I just don't believe it is relevant to this particular question.